# QueryContinueDrag is still called despite being canceled

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to handle **Drag and drop** in WPF. My application will handle when the user **dropped** outside window.

The problem is that even when I did `e.Action = DragAction.Cancel`, `QueryContinuedrag` event continues to be called.

My code:

```
        private void _tabControl_QueryContinueDrag(object sender, QueryContinueDragEventArgs e)
        {

            if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
            {
                e.Action = DragAction.Cancel;
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("debug");
                //Handle
            }
            else
            {
                e.Action = DragAction.Continue;
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            }
        }
```

Result

[image: result]

Do I really have to cancel it? Or is there a way for me to catch the **Cancel Drag** event? Hope the helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle `UIElement.PreviewQueryContinueDrag`, the tunneling version of the `UIElement.QueryContinueDrag` event, and mark the event as handled.

Some bubbling events are dominantly handled by the handling control and require handling the tunneling version in order to override the default behavior.

```cs
ctor()
{
  this.PreviewQueryContinueDrag += TabControl_QueryContinueDrag;
}

private void TabControl_PreviewQueryContinueDrag(object sender, QueryContinueDragEventArgs e)
{
  if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
  {
    e.Action = DragAction.Cancel;
    e.Handled = true;

    this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("debug");
    //Handle
  }
  else
  {
    e.Action = DragAction.Continue;
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
  }
}
```